# Low memory vs total memory in "free" command

Tags: linux, memory, aws, 64bit, free

I am trying to understand the output of the `free` command on an AWS Linux server. For example, `free -h` gives:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        2.2G        4.0G         16M        9.0G         12G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Whereas `free -hl` gives:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        2.2G        4.0G         16M        9.0G         12G
Low:            15G         11G        4.0G
High:            0B          0B          0B
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

How can the "Low" used memory (11G) exceed the total used memory (2.2G)? From everything I'm reading, `-l` is supposed to split the totals into totals for "low" and "high" memory, which isn't even a distinction that's supposed to exist on 64-bit systems. What does the 11G actually mean then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the “Low” and “High” lines, the “used” columns doesn’t filter by purpose. To compare the values there to those given in the “Mem” column, you need to add the latter’s “buff/cache” column.